# How to modify progress bar value in Godot4 from player's script when an object touches it?

Tags: user-interface, progress-bar, godot, gdscript, godot4

Recently I am learning godot4 but I have a problem, how to change the value of the progress bar when an object touches it, What can I do if I want to change the value of the progress bar from the player's script?

I was trying almost all the things in the internet about this problem but no one says about this for godot4
Please anyone help me

Comment: I don't know the relationship between the object, the player, and the progress bar. Neither semantically, nor in the scene tree. However, perhaps this is useful to you: [Increment score when player touches a coin's Area2D](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/205264/10408).

Answer (score 0):

I’m guessing you mean something life health bar. You can modify the value of the progress bar like these:

```
$Progressbar.value -= damage_amount
```

But if you mean something else, then kindly specifier also a screenshot can be help or link that describes what you are trying to achieve.